# Using Javascript to insert url into Django template

Tags: javascript, html, django, mapbox

I made a map application using Mapbox, where a user can click on a feature and a popup shows with details about the feature. I would also like to provide a link in the popup to the DetailView of the object using Javascript, but I'm having trouble generating the anchor tag. So far I have

```
new mapboxgl.Popup()
  .setLngLat(e.lngLat)
  .setHTML('<a href="{% url app_name:view pk=foo %}">To Detail View</a>')
  .addTo(map);
```

But when I try it out on the development server, it gives me a 404 error with a request url of
http://127.0.0.1:8000/map/%7B%25%20url%20app_name:view%20pk%3Dfoo%20%25%7D

How do I get it to pass the correct url? I've also tried inserting the link into a normal HTML div and I get the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like its not recognizing your template tag as a template tag. Your syntax looks fine. Are you trying to use the url template tag in a javascript file? If so it wont work. You can only use template tags in the html files.

If this is in a html file, can you post the full code?

Comment: Yes it was in a javascript file. Moving it to the html file worked! Thanks very much